# Can't get GMX IMAP to sync

Tags: email

Im trying to get my free GMX mail to sync using IMAP to my WP7. I am using my username and password as you would expect and:

Incoming Server: imap.gmx.com:993:1 I have also tried ..:143 (so without SSL) and I have deselected/selected the SSL options under advanced for each. I have also tried with imap.gmx.co.uk and just plain address with no port number.

It appears as though I am the only one having this trouble, all Google Search's reveal are instructions for setting generic devices.

I managed to get POP working, but would prefer IMAP.

Comment: You asked a very specific question. I only can say that I am currently using Windows Phone with IMAP and Exchange accounts.

Comment: IMAP is a GMX premium feature. Did you upgraded your account?

Comment: @MarcelJanus No, not for the .co.uk version at least. What version are you on?

Comment: @tim.baker I looked in the German FAQ

Comment: @MarcelJanus ... then I guess it must be for the German version of GMX. Either way think this should help if you do have IMAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have struggled with this a few times; in the hope this helps someone else follow these steps.

A couple of notes:

> - These instructions include details for GMX mail, but it should help if you are having issues with receiving email on your Windows Phone
> - Set up like this I have avoided most error messages including "there is a problem with the certificate for"
> - These are instructions for using IMAP; you can adjust for using POP though I'd always [recommend IMAP](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en)
> - You will notice the server is gmx.com; I have a .co.uk address and the two play nicely together
> - After the "Incoming email server" notice how I have **not** entered any port numbers (some sites suggest imap.gmx.com:993)

**1. Start fresh**

It has given me problems before because it has recognise the email etc - so delete the email account if you have already tried to set it up.

**2. Go in to Settings>Email+Accounts>Add an Account>Advanced Set Up**

Make sure you select advanced and not other account

**3. Enter your email/password**

**4. Select "Internet Email"**

**5. Set the following settings**

- Account Name = Whatever
- Your Name = Whatever
- Incoming email server = imap.gmx.com
- Account Type = IMAP
- Username = Your GMX Email
- Password = Your password
- Outgoing = smtp.gmx.com
- Outgoing server requires... = CHECKED
- Use the same username... = CHECKED
- [Advanced] Require SSL for incoming = CHECKED
- [Advanced] Require SSL for outgoing = BLANK

Answer (score 2):

My GMX account works with `imap.gmx.com:993:1` as the incoming server. My user name is my email address (the primary one if you've set up aliases).

Under "advanced settings" I've got "Require SSL for incoming email" checked.